# How to create a grey image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I tried to create a grey 3x3 pixel image in python, however the result is always a black image with several coloured pixels.

What I tried:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

greyimg = np.array([[[128]*3]*3]*3)
print(greyimg)
Image.fromarray(greyimg, 'RGB').save("test_grey.png")
```

What I expected:
a grey 3x3 image

What I got:
[a coloured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KoUt.png)

Comment: you should specify the datatype as`greyimg = np.array([[[128]*3]*3]*3,dtype=np.uint8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

greyimg = np.array([[[128]*3]*3]*3,dtype=np.uint8)
print(greyimg)
Image.fromarray(greyimg, 'RGB').save("test_grey.png")
```